# Are there any legendary characters created specifically for Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Are there any Legendaries which were made up specifically for HearthStone?

Or are they all characters pulled from Warcraft lore?

For example, I don't know Lord Jaraxxus or Dr. Boom.

Comment: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com does a good job of linking lore. For example [this is Dr. Doom's lore](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Dr._Boom#Lore) and [this is Lord Jaraxxus' Lore](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lord_Jaraxxus#Lore)

Comment: Specifically with regard to your examples, Dr. Boom is from a quest in Netherstorm from The Burning Crusade Expansion and Lord Jaraxxus is the second raid boss from the Trial of the Crusder raid from the Wrath of the Lich King expansion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not a legendary, before The Grand Tournament the only new character was [Harth Stonebrew](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_innkeeper). But in recent expansions there has been some. TGT added a few original legendaries:

- [Skycap'n Kragg](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Skycap%27n_Kragg)
- [Nexus-Champion Saraad](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nexus-Champion_Saraad)
- [Bolf Ramshield](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Bolf_Ramshield)

And from League of Explorers these are original:

- [Arch-Thief Rafaam](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arch-Thief_Rafaam)
- [Reno Jackson](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Reno_Jackson)
- [Elise Starseeker](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Elise_Starseeker)
- [Sir Finley Mrrgglton](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sir_Finley_Mrrgglton)

You can check the full list (including newer expansions, spells and other cards) in [Hearthstone's wiki at Gamepedia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Original_characters_in_Hearthstone).

Answer (score 6):

All of the legendary cards in Hearthstone are from Warcraft lore. All legendaries are specific characters, like a raid boss or unique weapon.

Comment: The card list isn't needed at all; it obscures the main point, and the answer to the question.

Comment: @Frank Okay. Fixed.

Comment: @ChaseC Not saying you need to do this, but a list that would really be awesome is one referencing the lore for each character.

Comment: @JonathanMee http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards?filter-rarity=32

Comment: @ChaseC Ah, I see, I can click on each name and get a little blurb about the lore.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yeah, there aren't really a lot of good places to link hearthstone and wow lore, but you can look up individual cards.

Comment: Was Leeroy Jenkins (officially) added to Warcraft lore?

Comment: @SBoss Great question. In the updated version of Upper Blackrock Spire, Leeroy's body can be found in the Rookery next to Kyrak. On heroic mode, he can be resurrected provided the group has not yet proceeded to the next area. Resurrecting him will begin a 900 second countdown, then Leeroy will charge into battle and make his way towards the Son of the Beast. If Leeroy successfully makes it to the Son of the Beast's corpse and acquires his Devout shoulders, the players will be awarded an achievement and recruit Leeroy as a garrison follower.